# 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

```
for i in Train.index :


    preds = nx.jaccard_coefficient(G, ebunch = (Train['source_node'][i], Train['destination_node'][i]))
    for u,v,p in preds:
        print('(%d, %d) -> %.8f' % (u, v, p))
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-95e128c1b501> in <module>()
      3 
      4     preds = nx.jaccard_coefficient(G, ebunch = (Train['source_node'][i], Train['destination_node'][i]))
----> 5     for u,v,p in preds:
      6         print('(%d, %d) -> %.8f' % (u, v, p))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\algorithms\link_prediction.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    136             return len(cnbors) / union_size
    137 
--> 138     return ((u, v, predict(u, v)) for u, v in ebunch)
    139 
    140 

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What type of objects are `Train['source_node'][i]` and `Train['destination_node'][i]`?

Answer (score 0):

The argument `ebunch` must be an iterable of tuples.  You haven't shown enough code for us to know what `Train['source_node'][i]` and `Train['destination_node'][i]` are, but based on the error message, I suspect they are `numpy.int64` objects.  In that case, you need to nest these one level further in the `ebunch` argument.  For example, here I set `ebunch` to be a list containing a single tuple:

```
preds = nx.jaccard_coefficient(G, ebunch = [(Train['source_node'][i], Train['destination_node'][i])])
```